# Angular-Material: Tabs Performance with IE

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-material

When I use  with some content, the performance when using Internet Explorer is really poor. It improved significantly when i upgraded to angular-material 0.11.1, but is still poor (content mainly consists of md-lists, but no tab has more than 12 items..). The performance gets even worse if I need to use the md-dynamic-height directive.

```
/*UPDATE: 
*********

ADDED FIDDLE 
See fiddle with IE and Chrome for comparison*/
```

https://jsfiddle.net/72fxcg1m/1/

So I have two Ideas:

(1) Is there any way to load the tab content only, if the tab which should present it is active?

Like we have 4 tabs each containing 5 items:

Page load: Tab 1 is active, its content is loaded.
Content of Tab 2,3,4 is not part of the dom yet.

User clicks tab 3

1. Content of Tab 1 is removed
2. Tab-change animation
3. tab-change animation finished: content of tab3 gets added to dom (we could use some kind of loading animation here..)
4. show the content to the user

(2) adjust height before content gets shown

1. First do the change animation
2. load the content
3. adjust the height of the container
4. show the content to the user

Comment: You might want to include some of your code where you think the problem is possibly occurring, or even better- a fiddle with a running example of your problem.

Comment: no idea ajmajmajma? :)

Comment: I haven't looked super closely but I can tell you that angular-material uses flex for most if not all of it's layouts. IE does not seem to love flex - check this out http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox (this may be part of your problem but I am honestly not 100% sure)